# Pointer as a member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I want to create a class which has several pointers to other instances of this class. I want to create game of life where I can set the neighbour cells.

The problem that I have is that I can't assign a reference to my const pointer member variables.

```
class Cell {

            ...
        const Cell* left;
            ...

        void setLeft(const Cell & left) {
        this->left = left;
    }
}
```

I had the idea to save all cells in a vector something like this

```
std::vector<Cell::Cell> cells;
```

and then access and set them like this `cells[pos].setLeft(cells[left]);`(pos and left would be integers)

I get the following error msg. `Can't convert const cell to const cell* in assignment`.
Also it can't find the method `setLeft`

I come from a java/net background so maybe I just made a huge mistake.

Comment: Read the error carefully again and notice how it says "convert X to Y" and how X and Y are different types.

Comment: I'm too lazy to test this, but using `const Cell& left` might do the job.

Comment: @Rook that wouldn't work, since you cannot assign to a reference. It can only be initialized.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, oops. derp. I'll be quiet now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up pointers and references (which is understandable when you're comming from java/net). In C++, there is a clear distinction between:

1. `Cell x;`, an object (instance) of class `Cell`
2. `Cell *x;`, a pointer to an instance of `Cell`
3. `Cell &x;`, a reference ("another name") to an instance of `Cell`

Java "references" are equivalent to C++ pointers.

In your case, there are several issues. First, `setLeft()` needs to get the address of its argument, like this:

```
void setLeft(const Cell & left) {
  this->left = &left;
}
```

Second, unless the class `Cell` is defined in a namespace `Cell`, the vector would have to be typed just `std::vector<Cell> cells;`.

However, even more dangerous is the fact that your vector contains *statically* allocated `Cell` objects (its template argument is a class type, not a pointer). `std::vector` is allowed to move objects around in memory when it's added to, so once this happens, all existing pointers to objects stored in `cells` will become dangling. What you should do is store pointers in the vector instead:

```
std::vector<Cell*> cells;
cells[pos]->setLeft(*cells[left]); //assuming setLeft() still takes a reference
```

It might actually be even better to use smart pointers (`std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`) instead of raw pointers, but that's a separate topic.

Comment: Ok thanks you helped me a lot. But I have one follow up questions. Do you have any idea why I am not able to acces the method of cells in the vector? `cells[0].setLeft(...);` setLeft is declared in the public block, but I am not able to get any access to a cell. Maybe because I am using a namespace?

Comment: @MaikKlein How exactly are you "not able?"

Comment: eclipse tells me that it is unable to resolve the method `setLeft` nor any of its public method/member variables.

Comment: Is it just Eclipse complaining, or the compiler? I don't use Eclipse, but I've seen quite a few questions here on SO which bolied down to "the compiler is happy, but Eclipse just doesn't see it."

Answer (score 1):

Your `setLeft` function is taking a `Cell` by const reference, and you are attempting to assign that to a pointer to `const Cell`. You need to assign a pointer to a pointer:

```
void setLeft(const Cell* left) {
    this->left = left;
}
```

Then you have to pass it a pointer to a `Cell`. For example:

```
Cell a;
Cell b;
a.sefLeft(&b);
```

Answer (score 1):

add ampersand before the cells[left]. What you do is that you assign the instance to the pointer value.

```
cells[pos].setLeft(&cells[left]);
```

In general the & before the variable gives you the address of this variable.

EDIT:

after you edited your example you should replace & with *. The star operator before variable gives you the instance (or reference) from the pointer. Simply said... :-)

Comment: Is that an entirely safe thing to do? A direct pointer into a `std::vector` may become invalid following a resizing, right?